# Is there mistake in my code of printing highest and second highest number from array?

Tags: python, max, min

```
from array import *

array1 = array('i', [10,5,99,88,99,99,10,12,9,9,13,45,45,18,21,13,13,22,99])
#array2 = array('i', [10,5,99,88,99,99,10,12,9,9,13,45,45,18,21,13,13,22,99,88])
print(array1[len(array1)-1])
if(array1[0]>array1[1] ):
    fh = array1[0]
    sh =array1[1]
elif(array1[0]<array1[1] ): 
    fh = array1[1]
    sh =array1[0]
for i in range(2,len(array1)):
    if(array1[i]>fh):
        sh = fh 
        fh = array1[i]
    elif((array1[i] > sh) or (array1[i] < fh)):
        fh = fh 
        sh = array1[i]
    elif((array1[i] == sh) or (array1[i] == fh)):
        continue
    elif(array1[i] < sh):
        fh = fh
        sh = sh
print("fhighest = {} and shighest = {} ".format(fh,sh))
```

When i try to find out the highest and second highest number from `array2` which is commented it is showing correct output but with the case of `array1` both highest and second highest number are showing as 99.

Comment: Think about the condition `(array1[i] > sh) or (array1[i] < fh)`.

Comment: isn't is possible for you to sort it and find both? wouldn't it be more efficient?

Comment: What happens when the first and second entries of `array1` contain the same value?

Comment: whats wrong ? like 99 99 are duplicate and are 2 largest values

Comment: Why dont use `.sort()`?

Comment: Sort is an overkill, especially for large lists. There are just two questions (first max and second max), but sorting a list with say a million items gives you million answers from which you 999_998 throw away.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to keep track of the current two highest values as you iterate over the array:

```
from array import *

array1 = array('i', [10,5,99,88,99,99,10,12,9,9,13,45,45,18,21,13,13,22,99])
h1, h2 = float('-inf'), float('-inf')

for n in array1:
    if n != h1 and n != h2:
        if n > h1:
            if (h1 := n) > h2:
                h1, h2 = h2, h1

print(h1, h2)
```

**Output:**

```
88 99
```

Comment: @DanielHao 3.8 which is 3 major versions prior to the current release